# Write the "src" attribute when I click a image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, api

I have this code for make a image search trough Google Image API:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#envio').click(function(){
            var iURL = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images";
            $.ajax({
                url: iURL,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data: {
                    v:  '1.0',
                    q:  $('#query').val(),
                    format: 'json',
                    jsoncallback:  '?'
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    var html = '';
                    var j = 1;
                    $.each(data.responseData.results, function(i, v) {
                        html += '<img id="' + j + '" src="' + v.tbUrl + '" title="' + v.title + '" alt="' + v.title + '"/>';
                        j++;
                    });
                    $('body').append(html);
                },
                error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                    console.log(xhr.statusText, textStatus, error);
                }
            });                
        });
    });
```

I have a INPUT field and need when I click a IMG the value of SRC attribute goes there. I try with this code but didn't work:

```
$('img').click(function(){
    $.each(function(){
        $('#urlimagen').val($this.src);
    });
});
```

Also by default the first code just return 4 images and I need more than four, then my question around this code is as follow:

1. does any body know how to get more than 4 images?
2. can any help me to fix the image code? I mean when I click a image the SRC value must be in INPUT called #urlimagen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the code you use to append your image, and make sure you are assigning the click event handle at that time, not before.

```
$.each(data.responseData.results, function(i, v) {
    var $img = $('<img />'); // create a new image object

    // change image attributes
    $img.attr({
        'id': 'j',
        'src': v.tbUrl,
        'title': v.title,
        'alt': v.title
    });
    j++;

    // append image to DOM, remove your append statement and leave this here
    $('body').append( $img );

    $img.click( function () {
        $('#urlimagen').val( $(this).attr('src') );
    });

});
```

As for the 4 images returned, looking at your code it seems it depends on the length of the  `data.responseData.results` object, I don't know if you can modify that returned quantity.

Comment: This code accomplishes the exact opposite of the OP's goal :P

Comment: Edited with a better approach. Instead of creating the HTML with a big string, you create each image separately one by one, change its attributes, append it to the DOM and assign a handle for the click event. This way the click handle will be assigned after the image has been created, not before.

Comment: @Chris: "when I click a image the SRC value must be in INPUT called #urlimagen". The SRC value must be IN the input when the user clicks, so I suppose the image crs must become the value of the input.

Comment: Vice-versa - he wants the input value to be set to the image src. The code for creating images is definitely better than using yucky strings, I just think you've misunderstood the OP's aim with the click event. Take a look at my answer's comments, he posted a jsFiddle with a sample. His problem was the weird `each` thing, but also that he was applying the events before the AJAX success function ever had a chance to fire. I think I've sorted it out for him, but @user719427 really should take a look at the code here for creating images - much better than the current code.

Comment: I test this code too but if I leave as you suggested  `$('body').append( img );` then didn't work, if I change it to `$('body').append( $img );` it works but when I click any images the IMG attr is changed by the title in the body

Comment: Changed my code as Chris pointed out, but it wasn't clear from the question anyway.

Comment: Here, I've put his superior image creation code into a jsFiddle, along with the fix for your original issue. I don't really care which answer you accept, but I tell you that Jose took the time to clean up some other messy code first, so you ought to give him the upvote: http://jsfiddle.net/vprAy/  Also, @Jose, the variable you used, `$img`, would be less confusing if you just did `img` - the dollar sign in front of a variable while also using jQuery can get confusing, especially for new programmers.

Comment: @Chris: I'll leave you the ball, I'm getting crazy here ;) Anyway he should really create elements the right way to avoid problems... oh and by the way I forgot a dollar sign ($img instead of img). Good luck both :P

Answer (score 1):

If your html looks like this:

```
<img src="..." class="clickableImage" />
```

.. then you can use this javascript:

```
$('.clickableImage').click(function(){
    $('#urlimagen').val($(this).attr('src');
});
```

It will put the `src` attribute of the clicked image into the input with the id of `urlimagen`.

The `$('.clickableImage')` selector gets all elements with the class name `clickableImage`. `.click` adds a click event to each of these elements. Inside the function, `$(this)` will refer to the clicked image.  Using the `attr` method, you retrieve the `src` attribute of that clicked image and set it as the value of the form input using the `val` method.

If you can't or don't want to add the class name, you can make this apply to ALL images by using the selector `$('img')`, but I really suggest you use a class name if possible so you have control over which images are involved.

Now, if you want each clicked image's value to be **added** to the input value rather than replace it, use this instead:

```
$('#urlimagen').val($('#urlimagen').val() + ($('#urlimagen').val() > 0 ? ',' : '') + $(this).attr('src');
```

Each image you click will add a new item to the list.

Want an array instead? With the html:

```
<form id="urlimages"></form>
```

.. use the script:

```
$('#urlimages').append('<input type="hidden" name="images[]" value="'+$(this).attr('src')+'" />');
```

On the server-side, POST will contain an array of each image clicked.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong because doesn't work, please take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/ybWhR/

Comment: Need to add the click events in the success function, after the html is appended to the body. http://jsfiddle.net/Q75H3/

Comment: Good it works but I have one more question, with data.responseData.results comes a value called unescapedUrl and I want this in #urlimagen, could this be possible?

Comment: Yes, with unescapedUrl: http://jsfiddle.net/Snym5/ - Please, take a moment to read this code and try to understand it. Don't make this into a "GIVE ME THE CODEZ!" moment, take the time to learn what is happening. Look at the earlier code, compare it to this, figure out how I accomplished it, and grow your own knowledge as a result. Also... accept one of these answers and upvote the others :)

Comment: Good I want to accept your solution but I'm newbiew here and didn't know how to do this also I'm not trying to get GIVE ME THE CODE I like to learn from best just I was asking if it's possible

Comment: I understand you're new, just saying... your question got downvoted by a few people because they felt like it was "GIVE ME THE CODEZ", then after Jose and I hashed out a solution, you asked for a change without trying to experiment for yourself. I am not trying to lecture you or be a jerk, just want to encourage you to explore for yourself - give a man a fish, teach a man to fish, all that....

Comment: Seeing the code I think in two approach to get the attribute unescapeddUrl, first make this the SRC of the image and get a BIG image and second write it in a variable. For the one I have the answer is not so complicated for the two any tips in how to get the variable out of `each` method?

Comment: The last jsFiddle I posted (jsfiddle.net/Snym5) puts the unescapeddUrl into the `rel` attribute, then you can use `attr` to get it on click. You can also look in to element storage to store the whole data array in the element, use `element.store('dataName', data);` to store, `element.retrieve('dataName')` to retrieve. Now go fish. :P

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the time and I didn't know that about element I'm doing my first steps in jQuery you rocks

Answer (score 0):

```
$('img').click(function(){
        $('#urlimagen').val($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: This code is not valid. `.each` loops through an array, like this, which would loop all images on a page: `$('img').each(function (element) { /* do something to this element */ });`

Comment: Removed the each function from the code it should work now copy/paste fail